# How does MAM handle key exchange to initiate secure data messaging?

Tags: masked-authenticated-messaging

This is not my question, but a question asked on r/iota daily discussion. Could not find an answer, so though it might be good to add here.

Answer (score 4):

MAM doesn't dictate you how to distribute the key. You can use encrypted peer-to-peer connection, post service, carrier pigeons or the tangle itself. It's up to you.